# Vuejs. Update data() on update

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to check if there is an authenticated user in order to render the sidebar and the header.
If it's not authenticated the sidebar and header don't get rendered in order to display just the Login or Register. But my this.auth data is not getting updated until I reload the page. I understand that probably there is a feature on vuejs that will update this variable more often? ( My sidebar contains the router-links to load the rest of my components but this.auth does not get updated when I click on a router-link )

EDITED: Using a computed property solved it.

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <header-component v-if="auth" />
        <sidebar-component v-if="auth" />
        <router-view></router-view>
    </v-app>
</template>
<script>
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar"
import Header from "./components/Header"
    export default{
        name: 'App',
        components: {
            'sidebar-component': Sidebar,
            'header-component': Header,
        },
        computed: {
            auth ()
            {
                return (!localStorage.getItem("auth")) ? false : true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: the way you declare `  auth () {
                this.auth = (!localStorage.getItem("auth")) ? false : true
            }` work? it seem like incorrect,

Comment: Yes it works. I've just logged this.auth, before and after the condition and from false goes to true on created()

Comment: But that seems to work just on the page being loaded, it doesn't get updated after loading components on < router-view >

Comment: for my limit experience, I not sure about the ` watch?computed?created?updated?` mean,can you give me some link which explain it ?

Comment: Sorry. Maybe that was just more confusing. My point was that there must be a hook on vue's lifecycle to update the auth variable when the component or DOM changes. For example updated() or computed() but I don't know.

Comment: Oh , I understand, you can delete your `auth` declare  in the `data`, and use the `computed` like this: `computed {auth (){return (!localStorage.getItem("auth")) ? false : true}}`, try if it works

Comment: Thanks. I was trying that but probably I made some other mistake. Now it works when I update the DOM clicking on a router-link but it doesn't after login in (I log in and then I must refresh the page). I will try to fix that. Because computed property seems to be the proper way to do this.

Comment: @screwspike Yes, that works, I'm having some other issue, but computed property works just fine. You can post it as reply if you want and I will mark it as a solution.

Comment: thanks for your generous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete your auth declare in the data, and use the computed like this:

`computed {auth (){return (!localStorage.getItem("auth")) ? false : true}}`